# 51 V clamp on load dump; will this IC survive?

Tags: power, integrated-circuit, automotive, transient, iso

This is about the Texas Instruments [TPS2HB50-Q1 40-V, 50-mΩ Dual-Channel Smart High-Side Switch](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps2hb50-q1.pdf?HQS=dis-mous-null-mousermode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1692952851989&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.mouser.de%252F).

Vbb is the battery (suppy) voltage

Page 7 gives a `VbbCLAMP > 58V`

Page 6 gives

```
Maximum continuous supply voltage, VBB 36 V
Load dump voltage, VLD ISO16750-2:2010(E) 40 V
```

Will this chip survive a 51 V externally clamped load dump?

---

[image]

Comment: Depends how the schematic around it looks. Please post it.

Comment: My experience with destroying some TI motor drivers is that they can take about 2 more volts than what’s specified in the “absolute maximum” table.

Comment: With DGND or GND-GND there, I don't see why it would.  With RGND, maybe. What are the 'Load's?

Comment: @TimWilliams 24W 'bulb's, perhaps some led equivalents instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Load dump voltage, VLD ISO16750-2:2010(E) 40 V

> Will this chip survive a 51V externally clamped load dump ?

If you asked me? Nope.

But you should definitely post this question on the E2E TI forums, or even open a support case to have it clarified.

It'd also help you in understanding the spec to find the 16750-2 ISO standard and read on how those specifications and test methods are defined there. You'll then see how representative they are of your application.